# Вставка даты по умолчанию на HTML странице

Tags: html

Для выгрузки операций из БД на html-странице есть 2 окна для ввода периода времени "с" и "по".
Если написать в коде страницы: body onload = "ShowMonthDate();", то при входе на страницу поля для ввода дат заполнятся по умолчанию 01-08-2019 и 31-08-2019, так как сейчас август 2019.
Подскажите, как написать код, чтобы даты на странице были не для текущего месяца, а для предыдущего, т.е. чтобы отображалось 01-07-2019 и 31-07-2019?

Comment: `ShowMonthDate()` переписать так, чтоб выводила предыдущий месяц.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!
Оказывается, ShowMonthDate(); - это не встроенная функция. Она была написана и хранилась в папке сайта в файле /html/js/date.js
Там я подправил и выводит уже предыдущий месяц. Всем спасибо!